# My Java Error constructor, in class, cannot be applied to given types;

Tags: java, bluej

I am a beginner and trying to compile my work. However it doesn't work. I get this error

```
"constructor account in class account cannot be applied to given types;
required: in,java,lang,String; found: no arguments; reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in..."
```

If anyone could explain this to me would be very thanksful.

Comment: Post your tried code

Comment: Most likely, the constructor receives a `String` argument, but is being called with no arguments at all. Seeing the code, however, would clarify this.

Comment: Please post the account class code and the code where you are trying to create instance of account.

Answer (score 5):

This very likely means you forgot to pass arguments to the constructor.

```
class Account {
    Account(String name) {
      // ....
    }
} 

// somewhere in the code:
Account account = new Account();  // invalid, no arguments found, java.lang.String needed
Account account = new Account("some name");  // ok
```

Note that in Java when you add a constructor with argument(s), the default argument-less constructor is *not* generated automatically and you have to provide one by yourself:

```
class Account {
    Account() {   
      // ....
    }

    Account(String name) {
      // ....
    }
} 

Account account = new Account();  // ok
Account account = new Account("some name");  // ok
```